# Elements with different names in a sequence

Tags: xml, schema

How do I define schema for the following XML:

```
<root>
    <elements>
        <element1/>
        <element2/>
        <element1/>
    </elements>
    <elements>
        <element2/>
        <element1/>
    </elements>
    <elements>
        <element1/>
        <element2/>
    </elements>
</root>
```

where the number of elements **element1** and **element2** is unlimited and they can be intermixed in a varying order. Is it at all possible? Or should I just redefine XML as:

```
<root>
    <elements>
        <element type="1"/>
        <element type="2"/>
        <element type="1"/>
    </elements>
    <elements>
        <element type="2"/>
        <element type="1"/>
    </elements>
    <elements>
        <element type="1"/>
        <element type="2"/>
    </elements>
</root>
```

Comment: Just a side note, none of the codes you posted is a valid XML, the closing tags have to have `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema of your first structure

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="elements">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="element1" />
                                <xs:element name="element2" />
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema definition of your second structure

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="elements">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="element">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Visual Studio schema generator, you can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="elements">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="element1" />
                <xs:element name="element2" />
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```